# I want to remain Deleted data in database

Tags: php

I don't want delete student data from my database but don't show that in list i have coded to delete permanently from database can any one know about deleted query?

This is my fetch list code

```
<?php

    $query="SELECT id,name,fname,phone FROM  student"; 
$resultset=$connection->query($query); 

$count=0; 
while($r=$resultset->fetch_assoc()){
    $count++; 
echo "<tr><td>".$count."</td><td><a href='#'>".$r["name"]."</a></td><td>".$r["fname"]."</td><td></td><td><td>".$r["phone"]."</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='chb".$count."' value='".$r["id"]."'></td></tr>
"; 

}
?>
```

And this is my delete function code

```
function std_delete($id){
    $connection=new mysqli("localhost","root","","sms"); 

$connection->query("delete from student where id=".$id); 


for ($i=1; $i < 100; $i++) { 
    //echo "chb".$i."<br>"; 
    if(isset($_POST["chb".$i])){
    std_delete($_POST["chb".$i]); }
}}
```

Comment: Instead of deleting it, update a colunn with a flag, setting the row to inactive or hidden.

Comment: try setting a column deleted when a user want to delete something set delete = 1 other wise delete = 0, for all other query pass where deleted ==0

Answer (score 2):

Its called soft delete; instead of using delete just add a new column like active_ind (active indicator) of type boolean and make it false for deleteing the value...this way none of the rows get permanently removed.

While showing the records show the ones with active_ind set to true. Make sure to set the value of active_ind to true while inserting a new record.

Your sample delete query would be:

```
$connection->query("update student set active_ind = false where id=".$id);
```

Comment: why do you use such an cryptic name? `deleted` is simple as hell

Comment: depends upon your choice of column name :) active indicator seems more appropriate as it is general and tells whether your record is active or not. not just for deleteing it :)